# directline connection role and name not getting in BOT conversationUpdate

Tags: web-chat

//For reference below - DirectLine Connection code

````
```(async function() {
window.WebChat.renderWebChat({
directLine: window.WebChat.createDirectLine({
secret: “My KEY”}),
userID : "myid",
username: "myName"
},
document.getElementById('chat_converse')
);
document.querySelector('#chat_converse > *').focus();
})().catch(err => console.error(err));```
````

//Once Connected. We will have below objects in BOT.

````
```{
"type": "conversationUpdate",
"id": "ERqgImAulq3",
"timestamp": "2020-06-18T07:07:03.448Z",
"serviceUrl": "https://directline.botframework.com/",
"channelId": "directline",
"from": {
"id": "AicCk0YN2Ap9n2Ev1ovbuc-k"
},
"conversation": {
"id": "AicCk0YN2Ap9n2Ev1ovbuc-k"
},
"recipient": {
"id": "BotName@xp113vQdWDM",
"name": "BotName"
},
"membersAdded": [
{
"id": "BotName@xp113vQdWDM",
"name": "BotName"
}
]
}```
````

//From - section we should get id, name, role. In the "from" object name and role key is missing //and id is present but with auto generated id not actual user id myid.

Comment: `Role` isn't populated by Web Chat. I was able to populate `From.Id` and `From.Name` just fine. Can you please include your entire `index.html`, removing only your Directline Secret?

Comment: Hi @mdrichardson, Html file size is large not able to attach. After loading html I am getting some console error "Refused to get unsafe header "x-ms-bot-id" but connecting with bot. Only use actual id and name not getting in bot. Please assist me. Thank In Advance

Comment: However when I run in local emulator, I am getting required keys in from object. "from": {
    "id": "20148a80-f95c-474f-a7b5-daf6c95b789d",
    "name": "User",
    "role": "user"
  }

Comment: Please include all of your WebChat-related code from index.html, then. Again, I'm able to get this to work just fine, so it's likely something missing in your code.

Comment: Hi, Please find <script crossorigin="anonymous" src="https://cdn.botframework.com/botframework-webchat/latest/webchat.js"></script> <!-- Chat -->
 ConncectionCode, window.WebChat.renderWebChat({
directLine: window.WebChat.createDirectLine({
secret: “My KEY”}),
userID : "myid",
username: "myName"
},
document.getElementById('chat_converse')
);
document.querySelector('#chat_converse > *').focus();
})().catch(err => console.error(err));

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not getting a ConversationUpdate for the user, just the bot. You need to [send a ConversationUpdate manually](https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/tree/master/samples/04.api/a.welcome-event#overview):

```js
const store = window.WebChat.createStore({}, ({ dispatch }) => next => action => {
   if (action.type === 'DIRECT_LINE/CONNECT_FULFILLED') {
     dispatch({
       type: 'WEB_CHAT/SEND_EVENT',
       payload: {
         name: 'webchat/join',
         value: { language: window.navigator.language }
       }
     });
   }

    return next(action);
  });
```

Comment: Thanks @mdrichardson, It helps and got user details in bot

Answer (score 0):

I have applied as below in my code, It helps. May be useful for others

```
const store = window.WebChat.createStore({}, ({ dispatch }) => next => action => {
      if (action.type === 'DIRECT_LINE/CONNECT_FULFILLED') {
        dispatch({
          type: 'WEB_CHAT/SEND_EVENT',
          payload: {
            name: 'webchat/join',
            value: { language: window.navigator.language }
          }
        });
      }

      return next(action);
    });

    window.WebChat.renderWebChat({
        directLine: window.WebChat.createDirectLine({
            secret: 'YourKey'
       }),
       userID : "UserID",
       username: "UserName",
       store
      },
      document.getElementById('chat_converse')
  );

    document.querySelector('#chat_converse > *').focus();
  })().catch(err => console.error(err));
```

It will trigger two time bot activity, One without user info, One with user info. So I did checked at bot side if user info contains name kay then load my initial dialog something like below..It got worked for me. Thanks @mdrichardson

```
if (membersAdded[cnt].id === context.activity.recipient.id && context.activity.from && context.activity.from.name
                && context.activity.channelId=='directline') {
                await dialog.run(context, conversationState.createProperty('DialogState'));
            }
```